# Puppet: Is it possible to call an instance method in a ruby template (era) that was returned from a custom function in a manifest?

Tags: ruby, puppet, erb

There is a custom function that returns a class instance.

```
Puppet::Functions.create_function(:'my_custom_function') do

  dispatch :make do
  end

  class Sample
     attr_reader :value
     def initialize( value )
       @value = value
     end
     def to_s()
       '<Sample %d>' % [ value ]
     end
  end

  def make()
     Sample.new(1)
  end

end
```

ie:

```
class myclass {
   $data = my_custom_function()
}
```

Is it possible to use the $data as a complex type in an ERB template?

Due to the "to_s" defined for the class this works:

```
<%= @data %>
```

yields

```
<Sample 1>
```

but it doesn't appear possible to access any of the instance methods (ie: @data.value)

When trying to access .value, the following error is typical:

```
  Detail: undefined method `value' for #<Puppet::Pops::Loader::RubyFunctionInstantiator::Sample:0x7ace1824>
```

Is accessing class methods at all possible? If so, how?

Thanks.

Comment: Puppet functions return values that are meant primarily to be consumed by Puppet DSL code.  The fact that there is no way for your function's `dispatch` call to express a supported `return_type` should be a clue that what you are trying to do is not among the use cases that Puppet custom functions are designed to serve.  I cannot confidently say that there isn't any way to do it, but I am very comfortable saying that if there is a way then you shouldn't use it.

Comment: Or more precisely, what you should not do is return an object from your function that is meant to be interpreted, anywhere, as having a data type outside the realm of those supported by the DSL.

Comment: Thanks @JohnBollinger - I'm not completely familiar with ruby, however your comment ". . if there is a way then you shouldn't use it" makes complete sense. If it was supported it would be easier.